# iOS generic screen designing

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ipod

My Team does different screen designs for different iOS screens such as iPad, iPad Mini, iPod, iPhone. Is there a common method to do this where a single design is done which supports/ fits all screens. Right now, we are facing more issues on different devices and different versions of the app. The above mentioned is for a completely native iOS app. Not a phonegap/ not a Titanium.

This is how we have done coding for different devices.

```
            if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
            if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
            {
                HelpView.frame=CGRectMake(7, 0, 300, finalheight+30);
                himgview.frame=CGRectMake(7, 560, 300, finalheight+30);
            }
            else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==480){
                HelpView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, finalheight+30);
                himgview.frame=CGRectMake(5, 555, 310, finalheight+30);
            }
        }
        else{
            if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
            {
                HelpView.frame=CGRectMake(7, 0, 300, finalheight+30);
                himgview.frame=CGRectMake(7, 550, 300, finalheight+30);
            }
            else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==480){
                HelpView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, finalheight+30);
                himgview.frame=CGRectMake(5, 555, 310, finalheight+30);
            }
        }
```

Comment: what you mean by different screen design? It's look different? Or Just create different nib for corresponding device?

Comment: In IOS, there is some different screen(dimension), iPhone retina 3.5", retina 4",iPad, iPad mini. So you can use two different xib for iPad and iPhone correspondingly. To fit for retina 3.5" and 4", use Autolayout. If your view is more complication, use another xib too.

Comment: I can understand the need to differentiate iPhone 3.5" or 4" and iPads, but what's the point between an iPad and an iPad Mini which has the same resolution?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question with the sample code done by my team. They have used this code to display a info button on different devices. Is this right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

By doing different screen designs, I assume you mean using different XIB's or storyboards?
If that's indeed what you're doing right I suggest you to take a look at [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).
That way, you just describe how you want your elements to be laid out and iOS will automatically lay them out based on the screen size. That way you could get away with just one or two (iPad and iPhone) storyboards thus removing the need to create a separate layout for each screen resolution.
Btw, even without Auto Layout, you don't really need different layouts for iPad and iPad Mini or an iPod 5 and iPhone 5, since these share the same resolution.

Comment: This is how we have done coding for different devices.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question with the sample code done by my team. They have used this code to display a info button on different devices. Is this right way to do it?

Comment: Thanks for adding the sample code. However, this isn't Auto Layout since you're setting all the frames yourself manually. This means you have a lot of work to do for every screen resolution and change your designers make. When your using Auto Layout, you shouldn't be settings the frame property anymore, Auto Layout should calculate the frame using the current screen size and your own constraints. That way, you don't need any of the sample code you posted anymore. I suggest you to take a look at Apple's own Auto Layout introduction and the 'Beginning Auto Layout' tutorial by Ray Wenderlich.